# BigIP F5 irule http_response variable getting reset before lb_selected event happens

Tags: big-ip, f5

I'll try to be as descriptive as I can since I'm not well trained in our F5 load balancers ways. Basically I have an iRule that looks something like this(pseudocode):

```
when HTTP_REQUEST { 
set host_num=0
if uri contains /serv prefix
       set host_num=(digit after /serv) 

}

when LB_SELECTED {
    if { $host_num != 0 } {
            #reselect the appropriate pool member that corresponds to the host_num
    }
}
```

My problem is basically that my host_num variable is lost between when I set it in HTTP_REQUEST and when I actually need it in the LB_SELECTED event.

This system worked flawlessly for years. Until a few days ago when I tried to add another irule that forced all http traffic to be http 1.0 instead of 1.1. I've removed this irule, but this problem still remains. Is there a setting in the HTTP profile that I'm missing? I've checked my other irules and none of them have a host_num variable that could be overwriting this, so what could be happening?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you have a tcl error here and the variable assignment must not contain equals sign.

Eg.

```
set host_num 0
...
if { .... } {
    set host_num (....)
}
```

Do you see any error messages in the /var/log/ltm log?

I would try adding logging statements in the code to trace the variable value changes.